# How to keep data persistent when switching tabs?

Tags: flutter, dart, pluto-grid

I have a Tab with 3 nested tabs ? when i switch from one tab to another the data that i entered in tab 1 is not peristent,

I am working with `PlutoGrid`
this is the code below

```
class WeeklyRoster extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<WeeklyRoster> createState() => _WeeklyRosterState();
}

class _WeeklyRosterState extends State<WeeklyRoster>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? captainData;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? firstOfficerData;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? cabinCrewData;
  PlutoGridStateManager? _stateManager;
  List<PlutoColumn>? columns;
  List<PlutoRow>? plutoRows;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? _globalData;
  String globalType = "captain";
  DateTimeRange _dateRange = DateTimeRange(
    start: DateTime.now(),
    end: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 10)),
  );
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    captainData =
        Provider.of<RosterDataProvider>(context, listen: false).captainSnapShot;
    firstOfficerData = Provider.of<RosterDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .firstOfficerSnapShot;
    cabinCrewData = Provider.of<RosterDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .cabinCrewSnapShot;
    _globalData = captainData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Weekly Schedule'),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final picked = await showDateRangePicker(
                  context: context,
                  firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                  initialDateRange: _dateRange,
                );
                if (picked != null && picked != _dateRange) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dateRange = picked;
                  });
                  // print('reach Date select weekly');
                  // print(' _globalData $_globalData');
                  _parseColumnRow(
                    _globalData,
                    globalType,
                    _dateRange.start,
                    _dateRange.end,
                  );
                }
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomOpacity: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: TabBar(
                onTap: (value) {
                  switch (value) {
                    case 0:
                      // print('on captain tab');
                      //  _globalData?.clear();
                      _globalData = captainData;
                      globalType = "captain";
                      // });
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      //  _globalData?.clear();
                      _globalData = firstOfficerData;
                      globalType = "firstOfficer";
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      //  _globalData?.clear();
                      _globalData = cabinCrewData;
                      globalType = "cabinCrew";
                      break;
                  }
                },
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(text: 'Captain'),
                  Tab(text: 'Copilot'),
                  Tab(text: 'Cabin Crew'),
                ],
                indicatorColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 249, 4),
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  PlutoGrid(
                    key: const ValueKey('captain'),
                    mode: PlutoGridMode.selectWithOneTap,
                    onSelected: (event) {
                      final PlutoRow row =
                          _stateManager!.rows.elementAt(event.rowIdx!);
                      final String userId = row.cells['NAME']!.value.toString();
                      const String firestoreCollection = "CAPTAIN_DATA";

                      openDetail(event.cell, event.cell!.column.field, userId,
                          firestoreCollection, context);
                    },
                    onLoaded: (PlutoGridOnLoadedEvent event) {
                      _stateManager = event.stateManager;
                      _parseColumnRow(captainData, 'captain', _dateRange.start,
                          _dateRange.end);
                    },
                    columns: columns ?? [],
                    rows: plutoRows ?? [],
                  ),
                  PlutoGrid(
                    key: const ValueKey('firstOfficer'),
                    mode: PlutoGridMode.selectWithOneTap,
                    onSelected: (event) {
                      final PlutoRow row =
                          _stateManager!.rows.elementAt(event.rowIdx!);
                      final String userId = row.cells['NAME']!.value.toString();
                      const String firestoreCollection = "FIRST_OFFICER_DATA";

                      openDetail(event.cell, event.cell!.column.field, userId,
                          firestoreCollection, context);
                    },
                    onLoaded: (PlutoGridOnLoadedEvent event) {
                      _stateManager = event.stateManager;
                      _parseColumnRow(firstOfficerData, 'firstOfficer',
                          _dateRange.start, _dateRange.end);
                    },
                    columns: columns ?? [],
                    rows: plutoRows ?? [],
                  ),
                  PlutoGrid(
                    key: const ValueKey('cabinCrew'),
                    mode: PlutoGridMode.selectWithOneTap,
                    onSelected: (event) {
                      final PlutoRow row =
                          _stateManager!.rows.elementAt(event.rowIdx!);
                      final String userId = row.cells['NAME']!.value.toString();
                      const String firestoreCollection = "CABIN_CREW_DATA";

                      openDetail(event.cell, event.cell!.column.field, userId,
                          firestoreCollection, context);
                    },
                    onLoaded: (PlutoGridOnLoadedEvent event) {
                      _stateManager = event.stateManager;
                      _parseColumnRow(cabinCrewData, 'cabinCrew',
                          _dateRange.start, _dateRange.end);
                    },
                    columns: columns ?? [],
                    rows: plutoRows ?? [],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _parseColumnRow(
    List<Map<String, dynamic>>? data,
    String type,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate,
  ) async {
    if (columns != null) {
      _stateManager!.removeColumns(columns!);
    }
    if (plutoRows != null) {
      _stateManager!.removeAllRows();
    }
    final columnTitles = List.generate(
      endDate.difference(startDate).inDays + 1,
      (index) =>
          DateFormat('dd MMM').format(startDate.add(Duration(days: index))),
    );
    columns = [
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'NAME',
        field: 'NAME',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
        width: 200,
      ),
    ];
    for (int i = 0; i < columnTitles.length; i++) {
      columns!.add(
        PlutoColumn(
          title: columnTitles[i],
          field: '$i',
          type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
          width: 100,
        ),
      );
    }
    plutoRows = [];
    final name = data!.map((e) {
      return e['NAME'];
    }).toList();
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
      String cap = "${name[i]} ";
      Map<String, PlutoCell> cells = {
        'NAME': PlutoCell(value: cap),
      };
      for (int j = 0; j < columnTitles.length; j++) {
        cells['$j'] = PlutoCell(value: '');
      }
      plutoRows!.add(PlutoRow(cells: cells));
    }
    await PlutoGridStateManager.initializeRowsAsync(
      columns!,
      plutoRows!,
    ).then((value) {
      _stateManager!.removeAllRows();
      _stateManager!.insertColumns(0, columns!);
      _stateManager!.appendRows(plutoRows!);
      _stateManager!.notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  openDetail(PlutoCell? cell, String field, String userId,
      String firestoreCollection, BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return SizedBox(
              height: 600,
              width: 200,
              child: AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Select a shift'),
                content: SizedBox(
                  height: 500,
                  width: 200,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: shift.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final s = shift[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(s),
                        onTap: () {
                          cell!.value = s;
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

as I go to the first tab `Captain` then enter some value in the cell , switch to another tab and come back that entry is gone, i have tried many ways like using provider, global variable, AutomaticKeepAliveMixin etc but failed, Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `PlutoGrid` out of function and use it directly in `TabBarView`
2. Add keys to all 3 pluto widgets, for example `key: ValueKey('pluto1')`, `key: ValueKey('pluto2')` and `key: ValueKey('pluto3')`
3. Add `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` mixin to `PlutoGrid`'s state and override `bool get wantKeepAlive => true;`
   or use it with `KeepAlive` widget:

   ```
   KeepAlive(
               keepAlive: true,                  
               child: PlutoGrid(
                 key: const ValueKey('captain'),
                    mode: PlutoGridMode.selectWithOneTap,
                    onSelected: (event) {
                      final PlutoRow row =
                          _stateManager!.rows.elementAt(event.rowIdx!);
                      final String userId = row.cells['NAME']!.value.toString();
                      const String firestoreCollection = "CAPTAIN_DATA";

                      openDetail(event.cell, event.cell!.column.field, userId,
                          firestoreCollection, context);
                    },
                    onLoaded: (PlutoGridOnLoadedEvent event) {
                      _stateManager = event.stateManager;
                      _parseColumnRow(captainData, 'captain', _dateRange.start,
                          _dateRange.end);
                    },
                    columns: columns ?? [],
                    rows: plutoRows ?? [],
                  )
              )
   ```

Comment: yes i updated the code as per your answer, i even updated my question, when i switch from the parent tab to the nest tab its there, but when i swipe or toggle within the nested tab, the data is not persistent, can you please check?

Comment: `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` should be in `PlutoGrid`'s state, not in `_WeeklyRosterState`

Comment: I don't get it , where exactly do you mean , can you show it in the code please  ?

Comment: add `PlutoGrid` widget code

Comment: its a package? https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_grid

Comment: ok, i see. Then put `PlutoGrid` into your widget and add there `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, or put it into `KeepAlive` widget with `true` parameter

Comment: If you see i have already done that in the code i have posted above, do you have any alternatives to TabBar where i need to show 3 data which will make my data persistant  ?

Comment: Thank for helping out but 
`Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget KeepAlive(keepAlive: true) wants to apply ParentData of type KeepAliveParentDataMixin to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the KeepAlive widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, KeepAlive widgets are placed directly inside SliverWithKeepAliveWidget widgets.
The offending KeepAlive is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.`